# "Project Collection Service Account" was by default not available few days before and today available for new VSO accounts

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When I created a new VSO account few days back then "Project Collection Service Account" was not available by default in the DefaultCollection group
but when today I created another new VSO account It was available by default, was it some random/expected behavior or was actually removed and then added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you the account owner of the other account? It may be that you did not have permission or that there was a temporary glitch.

That group is status there on every VSO and TFS account.

Comment: I was the owner of the account, but I noticed few things that are There is no "Project Collection Service Accounts" instead of that there is additional group "Team Foundation Service Accounts", I think that due to some glitch "Project Collection" is replaced with "Team Foundation" because same is happened for the groups "Project Collection Administrators" and "Project Collection Valid Users", they are now "Team Foundation Administrators" and "Team Foundation Valid Users" respectively, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should make no difference as the mean the same thing. Did you take a support ticket?